# Is there a way to check is a machine is accessible from its public ip?

Tags: ssh, openvpn

My purpose is to find out if a machine (here known as C1) is accessible from its public ip.

A few details:

- C1 private ip: 192.168.0.14 . C1 belongs to LAN 192.168.0.0-255 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.0.254
- C1 public ip: 169.159.xx.xx
- C1 public ip is natted so also all the clients belonging to the same LAN, have the same public ip (for example C3 having 192.168.0.50 as
  private ip, has the same public ip 169.159.xx.xx)
- C1 O.S is Linux (Debian)
- If I nmap C1 from C3 192.168.0.50, I get only 2 open ports: 22 and 443
- C1 has an openvpn installed
- It's impossible to connect to C1 through ssh using its public ip  (from C3)

How can I connect to C1 from a remote location?

Is there a way to check if C1 is actually accessible from outside?
The fact that I cannot access C1 through its public ip is that because 169.159.xx.xx is natted?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Just telnet to the port you want to check, over a public connection.

#### > telnet public-ip port

if connected, means accessible.

Comment: This is a valid answer for checking for a specific open port.

Answer (score 1):

Use online tool to check open ports,

http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Are you sure that is the public ip, cause i know 169.x.x.x is assigned when the device fails to obtain dynamic ip from the dhcp server ??

Comment: The AutoIP block is 169.254.0.0/16 not 169.0.0.0/8.

Comment: Thanks for your replies but the only ports open are 22 and 443.